# iOS text labels work on simulator and older devices, disappear on newer devices

Tags: ios, iphone, label

I am developing an app that has several vertical stacks of alternating buttons and text labels.  The app appears and functions fine in the simulator on all devices, but when downloaded onto actual devices, the text labels are not visible with newer devices such as iPhone X.

Comment: You'll need to provide considerably more information. *"the text labels are not visible"* ... have you used Debug View Hierarchy to inspect the layout? Are the labels there, and the debugger shows the text is set, but the characters are not visible? Are you using a custom font? Do you see the same issue if you have a single label on a view?

Comment: The text is visible (shown, black text on white background) in the storyboard as well as with the simulator when I run the app.  It shows up with any of the available devices.  I am using a System 14.0 standard sans serif font, with a little T all the way to the right.  It works fine when I download it onto my iPhone 7 but when downloaded onto an iPhone 8, X, XS, 11, no text shows up.  The space for the labels appears to be there, so it is not as if the label object is missing, but it is just empty space.  I was thinking it was some kind of strange overlap problem related to size constraints.

Comment: The only way to determine that is to inspect it. Give the label a green background color. Does it end where it's supposed to? Or does it look like it extends past the edge? Or does it look like it is covered by some other element? Really, your best bet is to use `Debug View Hierarchy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the default text color is different on the newer devices. Black text on the iPhone 7.  White text on a white background on the iPhone X was the problem. Weirdly, this issue was not correctly simulated on the simulator so debugging in XCode wasn't helpful- it had to be run on actual devices. Thanks DonMag for the suggestion on the background color.